# Save an isearch with complex terms

Tags: search, emacs

I have a log file which I fill with things going on in my life and later want to search. I would like to be able to search it interactively using terms that I save in some respect so I don't have to keep typing them in. For instance with `regexp-isearch-forward` I might use the term `"sleep\|nap\|tired\|exhausted\|woke"` to find all things relating to sleep and tiredness.

I'd like to put something like

```
(regexp-isearch-forward "sleep\|nap\|nap\|tired\|exhausted\|woke")
```

At the top of the file and run it with `C-x C-e` but that doesn't work. Can anyone suggest a solution that would provide the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not committed to `isearch`, you can use `occur` and `next-error`.

```
(defun my-occur ()
  (interactive)
  (occur "sleep\\|nap\\|nap\\|tired\\|exhausted\\|woke"))
```

`next-error` (`M-g n`, `M-g M-n`) and `previous-error` (`M-g p`, `M-g M-p`) cycle through the matches.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are already aware that you can retrieve previous search strings (during the same Emacs session), using **`M-p`** while searching - repeat to get older search strings.  But what more can you do?

**General approach:**

1. To save the current search string, for use with subsequent searches during the current Emacs session (e.g., after quitting Isearch), copy it to the kill-ring, using **`M-w`**.  (If you use [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) then this does not exit searching.  With vanilla Emacs it does.)
2. To yank whatever is in the kill ring at the end of the current search string, use **`M-y`** while searching.  (Repeating `M-y` yanks previous kill-ring entries.)

---

**More possibilities:**

The kill ring can change as you edit stuff.  If you want to save a search string a bit more persistently (but still only for the current Emacs session), you can save it in the [secondary selection](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection), in a variable, or in a register.

*Secondary selection*

If you use library [`second-sel.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/second-sel.el) then you can transfer the region selection to the secondary selection using `C-u C-M-y`.  Otherwise, just hold down the Meta key while dragging with the mouse, to select text for the secondary selection.

If you use Isearch+ then, while searching, you can yank the secondary selection onto the current search string using **`C-M-y`**.

*Variable*

You can save the search string in a variable using, for example, `M-: (setq foo C-y)` (yank the string from the kill-ring using `C-y`).

If you use Isearch+, you can then insert the variable's value at the end of the current search string while searching, using `M-: foo`.  **`M-:`** is bound during Isearch to command `isearchp-eval-sexp-and-insert`: You enter a sexp to evaluate (in this case, the variable), and the result of evaluating that sexp is appended to the search string.

*Register*

If you use Isearch+ then you can use **`C-x r g`** while searching to append the value of a register to the search string.  You are prompted for the register to use.  (You can use a register command, such as `copy-to-register` (`C-x r s`) to put a string into a register.)

*Persistence*

To save a search string persistently, so you can reuse it in future Emacs sessions, just use it as the value of a *user option* (which gets saved in your `custom-file` or your init file).

```
(defcustom my-search-string "sleep\|nap\|tired\|exhausted\|woke"
  "My favorite search string."
   :type 'string :group 'convenience)
```

Then, if you use Isearch+, just use `M-: my-search-string` to retrieve it while searching (see above).